# Retrieving a consumers full account number (non-masked)

Tags: yodlee

Is there an Api that will give me access to a consumers full account numbers (non-masked)

Using: getItemSummariesForSite will bring back a list off accounts, however the accountNumber is masked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the site, if FI provides the non-masked Account number then you can get it. But you need to connect with the Sales Representative for the same. By default you'll get the masked account number.